# Use Linq to iterate over ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
var strings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;

var names = (from d in strings
             select new ConnectionName(d.Name));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, but because `ConnectionStrings` does not implement a strongly typed `IEnumerable`, you have to tell LINQ what type the collection contains.

Use either `from ConnectionStringSettings d in strings` or `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Cast<ConnectionStringSettings>()`.

Comment: As sugested: ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Cast<ConnectionStringSettings>().Select(d => new ConnectionName(d.Name));

Answer (score 3):

You can loop with a foreach:

> Just use the conn property you're looking for

```
foreach (var conn in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Cast<ConnectionStringSettings>())
{
    conn.Name
}
```

Comment: Great Answer! Although this answer is useful it does not answer the specific question asked and may be of little use to the majority of people who find it looking for a way to use Linq to iterate over connection strings. I suggest editing your answer to include your solution as well as a solution using Linq. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Cast it to its type as it is `IEnumerable` not `IEnumerable<T>` See  [Enumerable.Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) :

> > Casts the elements of an IEnumerable to the specified type.

```
  var t = from c in connectionString.Cast<System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings>()
          select c.Name;
```