# How do I get a list of all connection strings in app.config

Tags: c#

In need to create an small console app, that takes two arguments:

1. File location for `app.config` file.
2. passkey
   My problem is that the console app needs to read the `connectionStrings` and Encrypt it and then save the encrypted text to the config file. I have looked, but have not found any solution for it.

My `app.config` file could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
     <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Conn1" connectionString="Data Source=Database1;Initial Catalog=DB12;User ID=User1234;Password=Qwerty123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="Conn2" connectionString="Data Source=Database2;Initial Catalog=DB12;User ID=User1234;Password=Qwerty123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
       </connectionStrings>
      <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
      </startup>
</configuration>
```

I have the encryption part are done. I just need to in this example to read those two `connectionstrings` and encrypt them each. Please note that the name of the `connectStrings` are different every time, since the console app are triggered by TFS build server.

Comment: There are a number of google posts on how to encrypt strings in your app config What have you tried?

Comment: So you want to change the connection strings at runtime right?

Comment: look at this 
 -
 https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/598863/EncryptionplusDecryptionplusConnectionplusStringpl

Comment: Why must the names change?  I guess if they must, then what you really want to ask is:  "How do I get a list of all connection strings in app.config?"

Comment: @DonBoitnott , The reason the name changes are because the console are being used for many different systems and the names then also changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Linq to iterate over ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012809/use-linq-to-iterate-over-configurationmanager-connectionstrings)

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want to change the `app.config` of a completely different app than the one doing the changing (encrypting)? If so, a config file is a simple XML. Read it with `XDocument` or whatever you like and treat it like any other XML.(And there is *plenty* of documentation on how to change/manipulate XML)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you don't really need the name of the Connection String but the connection itself. I believe you just need to go thru them with `foreach` and for each iteration you can get the connectionString till the last one in the app.config.

```
 foreach (System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings css in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
 {
   string connectionString = css.ConnectionString;  
   // encryption part
   // rewriting the connectionString in the app.config or however you want ot be done 
 }
```

You mentioned you got the encryption part done and all you need is reading the strings.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you don´t know the name of the connection string, you could try it like this:

```
ConnectionStringSettingsCollection connections = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;

if (connections.Count != 0)
{
    //go trough all available ConnectionStrings in app.config
    foreach (ConnectionStringSettings connection in connections)
    {
       //reading the ConnectionString
       string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connection.Name].ConnectionString;

       //writing the ConnectionString
       Configuration config =  ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
       config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[connection.Name].ConnectionString = EncryptConfig(conString); //just call your Encryption part here instead of "EncryptConfig()" 
       config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
       ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

came up with this to work with both app and web, note i did also need to change the values and save them to disk so couldn't just loop through

```
var appConfig = System.Web.HttpContext.Current == null
                ? ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
                : System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");

var needsToSave = false;
foreach (var appCon in appConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Cast<ConnectionStringSettings>())
{
    //do stuff
}
```