# SQL Server express custom client connection

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I am trying to create a multi user vb.net application with SQL Server Express 2014.

For database access I am using typed dataset and it is in a separate project than user interface project.
The connection strings are in the settings of the project for database access.

When I install the application for the user, it works on the machine where the SQL Server is installed, but the connection string could not be changed on another client machine to point to the correct SQL Server. For information I have set remote access on SQL server correctly and I am able to access through the SQL Server Management Studio.

How can I update the connection string on client machine for the project of Database access using Typed dataset.

Thanks.

Comment: _connection string could not be changed_ What does this mean exactly? You need a way to configure your application with the correct connection information. Did you provide a way to do that?

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're asking here. It sounds like you've got a connection string where the server name is `localhost` or something. Is that correct? If so how does the application get hold of the connection string that it's using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I need to install this application at various offices, where there will be one SQL Server Express and application installed, and 2/3 clients using the application. The server name will be different at each location so I cannot fix it. So I was looking for dynamically changing at run time through some configuration update so that user can select the server name and connection string will use that server name to connect.

Answer (score 0):

If it's work on the same machine the application is installed, this could lead to multiple issue:

1. in the connectionstring, do you have set the server to either localhost or "." ? Then, change the server to the one where the sql server is install. For the proper syntax, see https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/
2. from the machine where the application is install, can you ping the sql server ?
3. if you can ping the sql server, can you connect to it from the machine where the application is install using SSMS or osql  (using windows authentication or sql server authentication, depending of how you have set the connection).

if you can connect using ssms or osql, please post you code with the connection string and the open command along with the error message.

**EDIT:**

Then, use the app.config to define the the server(s) location and then  ask the user to select the appropriate server. see https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/416198/How-to-get-Connection-String-from-App-Config-in-Cs for an example:

app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CharityManagement"  connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=CharityManagement;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

C#

```
var connectionString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CharityManagement"].ConnectionString;
```

You can add many connectionstring as you want. See [How do I get a list of all connection strings in app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252613/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-connection-strings-in-app-config) for how you can enumerate them and let the user select the "good" one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Actually I need to install this application at various offices, where there will be one SQL Server Express and application installed, and 2/3 clients using the application. The server name will be different at each location so I cannot fix it. So I was looking for dynamically changing at run time through some configuration update so that user can select the server name and connection string will use that server name to connect.